# How to use PHP to find all elements in HTML and get all the positions?

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-parsing

I'm trying to find all the elements of a tag in HTML and get the starting and ending point.

Here's my sample HTML

```
some content <iframe></iframe> <iframe></iframe> another content
```

Here's what I have got so far for code.

$dom = HtmlDomParser::str_get_html( $this->content );

```
$iframes = array();
foreach( $dom->find( 'iframe' ) as $iframe) {
    $iframes[] = $iframe;
}

return array(
    'hasIFrame' =>  count( $iframes ) > 0
);
```

Getting the number of elements is easy but I'm not sure if HTMLDomParser can get the starting and ending position?

What I want is

```
array( 
 'hasIFrame' => true,
 'numberOfElements => 2,
 array ( 
  0 => array (
   'start' => $firstStartingElement,
   'end'   => $firstEndingElement
  ),
  1 => array ( 
   'start' => $secondStartingElement,
   'end'   => $secondEndingElement
  )
)
```

Comment: what do you mean with start and end positions?

Comment: The position of the element in the tag.

Comment: position of the string itself inside the whole string markup?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the official doc (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) you can easily found out how many elements of a type there is in your DOM :

```
// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
       echo $element->src . '<br>';
}
```

All you have to do is retrieving $html->find('iframe') and verify its size to know if there is at least once

Comment: I also want the position of the element as well. Not sure if the lib provides that as well?

Comment: The documentation does not provide any example of this kind of functionality but you can trick a bit to obtain what you want. If there is a way to retrieve and iterate over all the children, then you can deduct a position

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$html = "some content <iframe></iframe> <iframe></iframe> another content";
preg_match_all('/<iframe>/', $html, $iframesStartPositions, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
preg_match_all('/<iframe\/>/', $html, $iframesEndPositions, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);


$iframesPositions = array();
foreach( $dom->find( 'iframe' ) as $key => $iframe) {
    $iframesPositions[] = array(
      'start' => $iframesStartPositions[0][$key][1],
      'end'   => $iframesEndPositions[0][$key][1] + 9 // 9 is the length of the ending tag <iframe/>
    );
}

return array(
    'hasIFrame'        =>  count($iframesPositions) > 0,
    'numberOfElements' => count($iframesPositions),
    'positions'        =>  $iframesPositions
);
```